# Yup.string().required().nullable(): allow default value of undefined/null when inferring type

Tags: reactjs, typescript, yup

Does anyone know if it's possible to do the following without typescript errors that I have to hard ignore?

```
const mySchema = yup.object({
  foo: yup.string().required().nullable(),
  bar: yup.string().required(),
  buzz: yup.string().nullable()
});

type MySchemaType = yup.InferType<typeof mySchema> 

const initialValue: MySchemaType = {
  foo: undefined, // this says it must be a string <<<< 
                  // It 'should' be nullable and just required for the validation
  bar: '1',  // this is fine
  buzz: undefined // this is fine
}
```

Comment: What does `required` **and** `nullable` even mean?

Comment: Are you looking for `Partial`? https://tsplay.dev/ND2BxW

Comment: Perhaps.
These functions are specific to yup, which is a schema library,
It's just a way to define requirements for a model.
(I recommend using it for validation so far)

Comment: Ummm so is does using `Partial` work for your use case or not? And if not, why?

Comment: Partial didn't seem to work

Comment: Yes... but why or how? What are you looking for?